# Add value (ID) from database to an action button in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am trying to add the ID on an ActionColumn's button that is coming from the database. I have looked for answers but I don't seem to get one right. Here is my code:

```
    <?= 

       GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => [
                'ID',
                'Job Post',
                'Email',
                'Date Added',
                 ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'header'=>'Action',
                    'template' => '{search}',
                    'buttons' => [
                           'search' => function ($model) {
                                return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['value' => $model->ID]);

            }
            ]
      ],
    ],
      'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-bordered table-hover'],

    ]); 

    ?>
```

I am new to Yii2, to be honest. And I just saw on yii2's documentation on how to display a list from the database that is why I came up with that code above.

But I get an error

> "TRYING TO GET A PROPERTY ON A NON-OBJECT"

particularly on the line where `$model->ID` lies.

Please help.

**UPDATE:** Here is how I get the data from the DB. I'm using `SqlDataProvider`.

```
    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider ([
                  'sql' => 'SELECT a.user_jobpost Job Post,
                 b.email Email,
                 a.user_job_id ID,
                 a.user_job_date Date Added
                   FROM users_jobpost a,
                        user b 
                        WHERE b.id = a.user_id'  )];
```

**HERE IS WHAT IS DISPLAYED WHEN I USE** `var_dump($model)`:

`string(55) "/jobposter/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsearch&id=0"`

Comment: Is your field name `id` is ID or id? Check your model contains `id`. `var_dump($model);`

Comment: As the message is indicating, `$model` is probably not an object. So in case you are using ArrayDataProvider or you are retrieving the models as array, you should use `$model["id"]` to get the ID.

Comment: @InsaneSkull the ID that i'm trying to set to the search button is the ID you can found above the "Job Post". When I checked `var_dump($model);`, it returned the datatype and url of each item on the list.

Comment: @jeesus I used `SqlDataProvider`. I'm going to update my inquiry above with the sql code I did.

Comment: what you see after `var_dump($model);` update in question

Comment: @InsaneSkull done.

Comment: Nope, your model not return that kind if output. `'buttons' => [
                           'search' => function ($model) { var_dump($model);
                                return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['value' => $model->ID]);

            }`. Is this you tried?

Comment: @InsaneSkull When I try that, the error `Trying to get property of non-object` showed. So I removed the value `$model->ID` and the above update I added is what is showed on the screen.

Comment: do `var_dump($model); exit`;

Comment: @InsaneSkull the result is still the same. the datatype and the URL is showed on when using the `var_dump($model)`

Comment: Anyways `var_dump($dataProvider->models); exit;` and update output in question.

Comment: @jeesus just letting you know the `$model['id']`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of SqlDataProvider you cannot access data as objects but as array so replace

```
$model->ID
```

with

```
$model['ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

I seen you have confusion in attributes in table row. you are trying to use attributes instate of table row in columns array

First you need to create model class and search class of database table using gii tool of yii. let name of model is Jobpost.php and search is JobpostSearch.php

in model you can see table row defined as in database table in rules() function and it attributes in attributeLabels() function. you can change attributes value to what ever you want in attributeLabels() function of model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'required'],
        [['job_post'], 'string'],
        [['email'], 'string'],
        [['date'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'job_post' => Yii::t('app', 'Job Post'),
        'Email' => Yii::t('app', 'Email'),
        'date' => Yii::t('app', 'Date Added'),
    ];
}
```

Then create controller file and create action

```
class JobpostController extends Controller
{
     public function actionShow()
     {
          $searchModel = new JobpostSearch();
          $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

         return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

    }
}
```

then in create index.php in view folder and write this code

```
GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'columns' => [
            'id',
            'job_post',
            'email',
            'date',
             ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header'=>'Action',
                'template' => '{search}',
                'buttons' => [
                       'search' => function ($model) {
                            return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['value' => $model->ID]);

        }
        ]
  ],
],
  'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-bordered table-hover'],

]);
```

note: value in columns must be as defined in rule function in model jobpost.php